# Parsing JSON Url with an Array Response

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm running this code in php:

```
$jsonData   = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=306%20Evarts%20St%20NE%20Washington,%20DC%2020002&key=<hidden>');
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
var_dump($data);
```

with the following result (reformatted to be readable):

```
array(2) {
    ["results"] => array(1) {
        [0] => array(5) {
            ["address_components"] => array(7) {
                [0] => array(3) {
                    ["long_name"] => string(3) "306"
                    ["short_name"]=> string(3) "306"
                    ["types"] => array(1) {
                        [0]=> string(13) "street_number"
                    }
                }
                [1] => array(3) {
                    ["long_name"] => string(23) "Evarts Street Northeast"
                    ["short_name"] => string(12) "Evarts St NE"
                    ["types"] => array(1) {
                        [0]=> string(5) "route"
                    }
                }
                [2] => array(3) {
                    ["long_name"] => string(20) "Northeast Washington"
                    ["short_name"] => string(20) "Northeast Washington"
                    ["types"] => array(2) {
                        [0] => string(12) "neighborhood"
                        [1] => string(9) "political"
                    }
                }
                [3] => array(3) {
                    ["long_name"] => string(10) "Washington"
                    ["short_name"]=> string(4) "D.C."
                    ["types"]=> array(2) {
                        [0]=> string(8) "locality"
                        [1]=> string(9) "political"
                    }
                }
                [4]=> array(3) {
                    ["long_name"]=> string(20) "District of Columbia"
                    ["short_name"]=> string(2) "DC"
                    ["types"]=> array(2) {
                        [0]=> string(27) "administrative_area_level_1"
                        [1]=> string(9) "political"
                    }
                }
                [5]=> array(3) {
                    ["long_name"]=> string(13) "United States"
                    ["short_name"]=> string(2) "US"
                    ["types"]=> array(2) {
                        [0]=> string(7) "country"
                        [1]=> string(9) "political"
                    }
                }
                [6]=> array(3) {
                    ["long_name"]=> string(5) "20002"
                    ["short_name"]=> string(5) "20002"
                    ["types"]=> array(1) {
                        [0]=> string(11) "postal_code"
                    }
                }
            }
            ["formatted_address"]=> string(54) "306 Evarts Street Northeast, Washington, DC 20002, USA"
            ["geometry"]=> array(3) {
                ["location"]=> array(2) {
                    ["lat"]=> float(38.9248059)
                    ["lng"]=> float(-77.001318)
                }
                ["location_type"]=> string(7) "ROOFTOP"
                ["viewport"]=> array(2) {
                    ["northeast"]=> array(2) {
                        ["lat"]=> float(38.926154880291)
                        ["lng"]=> float(-76.999969019709)
                    }
                    ["southwest"]=> array(2) {
                        ["lat"]=> float(38.923456919708)
                        ["lng"]=> float(-77.002666980292)
                    }
                }
            }
            ["place_id"]=> string(27) "ChIJvysMWvjHt4kRjif4nyaEb7U"
            ["types"]=> array(1) {
                [0]=> string(14) "street_address"
            }
        }
    }
    ["status"]=> string(2) "OK"
}
```

How can I echo various values in the results for example `long_name` of address components?

Comment: `echo $data['address_components']['long_name'];` doesn't works?

Comment: @oscargilfc, `$data['results'][0]['address_components']` is an array (list) with 7 elements.

Comment: Sorry , it should be `echo $data['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['long_name'];`

Comment: I reformatted up your data dump with linebreaks and indentation so that it's easier to read, this doesn't exactly conform to the actual output of `var_dump` but it's a lot easier to read. I also removed your API key from the API call since that shouldn't have been included.

Answer (score 0):

you can use nested `foreach` to loop array ref : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
foreach($data['results'] as $result){
    foreach ($result['address_components'] as $value) {
        echo $value['long_name'] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access response data as shown below:

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=306%20Evarts%20St%20NE%20Washington,%20DC%2020002&key=API_KEY');     
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);

if($data['status'] == 'OK'){
    $latitude  = $data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $longitude = $data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    $formatted_address = $data['results'][0]['formatted_address']; 
}
```